# Keep track of the last read record in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

I have 2 databases in MySQL:

1) An input Latitude-Longitude_dB ('latlong_db', henceforth): It has the latitude and longitude of each reading from a GPS tracking device.

[image: input_latlong dB]

2) A Weather_db: I read the input latlongs from dB1, and calculate 'current' weather data for each pair of latlongs (eg: humidity, cloud_coverage) . This weather data is written into a Weather_db.

[image: weather_dB]

The issue is: I need to keep track of which record (which 'input latlong') was read last. This is so that I don't recalculate weather_data for the latlongs that I've already covered. How do I keep track of the last read input_latlong?

Thank you so much.

---

Edit: 
1) For those who have been asking about the 'database v/s table' question, the answer is that I am reading from 1 database and writing into the 2nd database. The 'config.json' to connect to the 2 databases is as follows:

```
{
"Tracker_ds_locallatlongdb": {
        "database": "ds_testdb1",
        "host": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
        "port": XXXX,
        "user": "XXXX",
        "password": "XXXXX"
    },
    "Tracker_ds_localweatherdb": {
    "database": "ds_testdb2",
        "host": "XXXXXXX",
        "port": XXXX,
        "user": "XXXX",
        "password": "XXXXX"
    }
}
```

2) My Python script to read from the `input_latlong_db` and write into the `weather_db` is outlined as follows. I am using OpenWeatherMap API to calculate weather data for given latitudes and longitudes:

```
from pyowm import OWM
import json
import time
import pprint
import pandas as pd

import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error



api_key = 'your api key'

def get_weather_data(my_lat, my_long):
    owm= OWM(api_key)
    obs= owm.weather_at_coords(my_lat.item() , my_long.item() )   #Use: <numpy.ndarray>.item:
    w= obs.get_weather()
    l= obs.get_location()

    city= l.get_name()
    cloud_coverage =w.get_clouds()
    .
    .
    .
    w_datatoinsert= [my_lat, my_long, w_latitude, w_longitude, city, weather_time_gmt,call_time_torontotime,
    short_status, detailed_status,
    temp_celsius, cloud_coverage, humidity, wind_deg, wind_speed,
    snow, rain, atm_pressure, sea_level_pressure,sunset_time_gmt ] #15 + act_latitude + act_longitude
    return w_datatoinsert

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
spec_creds_1= {}
spec_creds_2= {}
def operation():
    with open('C:/Users/config.json') as config_file:
        creds_dict= json.load(config_file)
        spec_creds_1= creds_dict['Tracker_ds_locallatlongdb'] 
        spec_creds_2= creds_dict['Tracker_ds_localweatherdb']
        try:
            my_conn_1= mysql.connector.connect(**spec_creds_1 )
            if (my_conn_1.is_connected()):
                info_1= my_conn_1.get_server_info()
                print("Connected ..now reading the local input_latlong_db: ", info_1)
                try:
                    my_conn_2= mysql.connector.connect(**spec_creds_2)
                    if (my_conn_2.is_connected()):
                        info_2= my_conn_2.get_server_info()
                        print('Connected to write into the local weather_db: ', info_2)
                        cursor_2= my_conn_2.cursor()
                        readings_df= pd.read_sql("SELECT latitude, longitude FROM readings_table_19cols;", con= my_conn_1)
                        for index, row in readings_df.iterrows():
                            gwd= get_weather_data(row['latitude'], row['longitude'])
                            q= "INSERT INTO weather_table_19cols VALUES(" +        ",".join(["%s"]*len(gwd))     +    " ); "
                            cursor_2.execute(q, gwd)
                            my_conn_2.commit()
                except Error as e:
                    print("Error while connecting to write into the local weather_db: ", e)
                finally:
                    if (my_conn_2.is_connected()):
                        cursor_2.close()
                        my_conn_2.close()
                        print("Wrote 1 record to the local weather_db.")
        except Error as e:
            print("Error connecting to the local input latlong_db: ", e)
        finally:
            if (my_conn_1.is_connected()):
                my_conn_1.close() # no cursor present for 'my_conn_1'
                print("Finished reading all the input latlongs ...and finished inserting ALL the weather data.")


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------



if __name__=="__main__":
    operation()
```

Comment: I think you have one `database`, with two `tables`. Is that right?

Comment: Actually, these belong to 2 different databases- the `input_latlong` is read from 1 database, and the weather data is written into a different database altogether. It is from different databases.

Comment: Are you sure these aren't two tables and not two databases? Can you share your code on how update that `weather_db` table? It sounds like you just need to update a new flag column on your source table `latitude_longitute_db` when you perform this `update` or `insert` into your target table `weather_db`. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question since it seems a little light on details since it seems like the right answer is "You keep track of the input_latlong records by keeping track of them..."

Comment: @JNevill: I hope the edits in the question help. Though, I have to confess- I fail to understand if the  solution would drastically differ , if they were from 2 different databases v/s if they were from 2 tables within the same database? Given the edited question, how would I know which record was the last read input_latlong ?

Comment: I think adding a new column in `readings_table_19cols` to indicate if it's been read would be a good solution. After submitting `INSERT INTO weather_table_19cols VALUES(...` you can then submit `"UPDATE readings_table_19cols SET new_col = 1 WHERE latitude ='" + row['latitude'] + "' AND longitude = '" + row['longitude'] + "';"` or something along those lines. This way you know for certain you've already read it and updated the other table.

Comment: Optionally that first `SELECT` could join the other `weather_Tables_19col` in on lat and long with a `WHERE` predicate of `weather_tables_19col.<primary_key_col?> IS NULL` meaning your lat and long have already been recorded in the target table.

Comment: Ok, you have two tables, one from each of two distinct databases.

Comment: @JNevill: Interesting . Adding an `UPDATE` statement after the `INSERT` sounds promising- but how would I then ensure, that the weather data is henceforth computed only on the records (latlongs) that are unread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the Input_latlong_table- the `readings_table_19cols`: I created an Autoincremented `readings_id` as the Primary key , and a column called `read_flag` whose default value was 0.
2. In  the `weather_table_19cols`: I created an Autoincremented `weather_id` as the Primary key.
3. Since my method involves reading an input latlong record and correspondingly writing its weather data into the `weather_table`, I compared the index of the `readings_table_19cols` and the `weather_table_19cols`. If they matched, that means that the input record was read, and I would set the `read_flag` to 1.

..

```
for index_1, row_1 in readings_df_1.iterrows():

                            gwd= get_weather_data(row_1['imei'], row_1['reading_id'] ,row_1['send_time'],row_1['latitude'], row_1['longitude'])

                            q_2= "INSERT INTO weather_table_23cols(my_imei, my_reading_id, actual_latitude, actual_longitude, w_latitude, w_longitude, city, weather_time_gmt, OBD_send_time_gmt, call_time_torontotime, \
                            short_status, detailed_status, \
                            temp_celsius, cloud_coverage, humidity, wind_deg, wind_speed, \
                            snow, rain, atm_pressure, sea_level_pressure,sunset_time_gmt) VALUES("  +  ",".join(["%s"]*len(gwd))     +    " ); "

                            q_1b= "UPDATE ds_testdb1.readings_table_22cols re,  ds_testdb2.weather_table_23cols we \
                             SET re.read_flag=1 WHERE (re.reading_id= we.weather_id);"  # use the prefix 'db_name.table_name' if 1 cursor is being used for 2 different db's

                            cursor_2.execute(q_2, gwd)
                            my_conn_2.commit()
                            cursor_1.execute(q_1b) # use Cursor_1 for 1st query 
                            my_conn_1.commit()
```